# Render Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: react-native

I am a student trying to learn react-native for school. I've encountered this error. Any idea how to fix this error?

'Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop'.

My code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/MaterialIcons';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  setCount(0);

  function onPressIncrease() {
    count++
  }
  function onPressDecrease() {
    count--
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>{count}</Text>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressIncrease}>
            <View>
              <Icon name="add" size={24} color="black" />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.emptySpace} />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressIncrease}>
            <View>
              <Icon name="remove" size={24} color="black" />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <StatusBar />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

All help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the setCount(0) in the beginning of your component right after **let [count, setCount] = useState(0);**

The reason is that after changing the state of the component React immediately re-renders the component. So after firs mount, on the second line you are setting the counter to 0 **setCount(0)** at this point React knows that the state is changed and makes the second render of the component. When rendering second time the same second ling with **setCount(0)** is triggered and another re-render is invoked by react.

Second issue is that you are changing the **counter** directly in onPressIncrease and onPressDecrease functions (count++ and count-- respectively). You have to replace this lines with setCount(prev => ++prev) and setCount(prev => --prev) respectively)

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues with this component.

Firstly you are setting the count to 0 on mount, which is causing your component to rerender (react mounts the component, sets the count to 0 which calls a rerender of the component, which sets the count to 0...).

Also, your `onPressX` functions are mutating state directly. They need to call `setCount` with a new value. e.g. `setCount(count + 1)`, or `setCount(previousCount => previousCount + 9001)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
setCount(0)
```

no need to use `setCount` as you are already passing default value to `useState(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i have faced this issue many time this is the reson why yu getting this issue.

You have to call a onPress in the right manner from the component is rendring the function without calling it again and again.

you have to change
`onPress={onPressIncrease}`  to `onPress={()=>onPressIncrease(}`